# WSO2 Aggregator in insequence

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Will the aggregator mediator work in insequence ?

I have a splitter which will split the messages to JMS queue. I have another proxy service which should collect the messages and aggregate it.

I have kept the aggregator in insequence. Am I logically correct ?

Regards
Guru
@gnanagurus

Answer (score 0):

Message aggregation cannot be done in the inSequence without having a iterate mediator placed in inSequence.

There is a correlation between the splitting and the aggregation.
You can only aggregate messages which are split using the iterate mediator or cloned using clone mediator within the same Proxy service.

If you can provide me more information on your scenario, I can help you further.